# How can a website detect and block PhantomJS with Mozilla user agent-tag?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am scraping a pool of URLs in a python selenium framework using PhantomJS.

First, I specify the user agent.

```
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)           
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87")
```

Next, I create the PhantomJS instance.

```
def create_phantomJS():                             
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe", desired_capabilities=dcap)
    return driver
```

Then, I get all visible text from the website (quick & dirty):

```
def use_driver(driver, URL):
    website = driver.get(URL) # this line is needed, the highlighting is a bug in 
    html = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//html")))
    text = (str(html.text.encode("utf-8",'ignore')))
    return text
```

When setting the URL to `"https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/"`, the output contains the following information:

```
Your User Agent is:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87
```

This confirms that the setup is working. However, my website of interest returns:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "URL" on this server.
```

*In contrast, this works with geckodriver which I don't understand. In addition, using `BeautifulSoup` or `requests` just returns robots.txt content, which means that something at the DOM side is able to specifically detect PhantomJS*

**Q1: How can PhantomJS be detected despite different user agent?**

**Q2: What does Geckodriver different in order to overcome this check?**

**Q3: Can this check be circumvented theoretically?**

Please note that I am interested in understanding the difference of both driver instances rather than doing something fishy.

Comment: Chrome *15*?  Seriously??  What happens if you try a more modern user agent string, like...`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36`?

Comment: thanks for your hint - now, I see the content of robots.txt just like I do when using BeautifulSoup

Comment: Is your question Answered or you are still expecting an Answer?